Changing reference of subdocument based on another subdocument
In order to be clear on the problem let me start with an example.
Imagining we have a collection of products where a product can have multiple brands and is sold in different shops, each shop can sell one or more brands of that product:
    {
      "name": "Pen",
      "shops": [
        {
          "name": "Target",
          "brands": [
            "BIC"
          ]
        },
        {
          "name": "Walmart",
          "brands": [
            "Parker"
          ]
        }
      ],
      "brands": [
        {
          "name": "BIC"
        },
        {
          "name": "Parker"
        }
      ]
    }

However, due to unforeseen circumstances we can no longer use the brand name as the referece, and instead we should use another identifier.
However, we have to update all existing documents on the collection to have it something like this:
     {
          "name": "Pen",
          "shops": [
            {
              "name": "Target",
              "brands": [
                "1"
              ]
            },
            {
              "name": "Walmart",
              "brands": [
                "2"
              ]
            }
          ],
          "brands": [
            {
              "id": "1"
              "name": "BIC"
            },
            {
              "id": "2"
              "name": "Parker"
            }
          ]
        }

Adding the id to the brands is relatively easy, however replacing the brands inside the shops is the real problem.
Is there a way in mongodb to update the shops subdocument to use the id of the shop instead of the name?
Something like:
db.products.updateMany({}, 
  { 
    $set: { 
      "shops.brands.$" : "$brands[name=$].id" 
    }
  }
)


If the brand "BIC" appears in another document, should it have the same ID in all documents or is it okay to have ID=1 in one doc and ID=2 in another?

It's fine to have different IDs between different documents

So here's an update command which would achieve what you want.

First, $map each brand to have the structure and id based on its index plus 1.

If you want the indexes to start at 0 instead of 1, remove the $add: [..., 1].
If you want them as strings, put $toString: {} around the $indexOfArray: {} part.
You mentioned that the same brand occurring in multiple documents doesn't need to have the same ID in different documents. Otherwise, this will need to be completely different.


Second, also $map each shop and nest a $map for each shop-brand based on its index. The id will be the same as above since they are done in the same $set step - so the "$brands" refers to the current value in the document, not what was set above. (You can even invert the two and the results will be the same.)

Edit: Since you asked "Is there a way to not have to mention on the map all the other fields that remain unchanged?" - I've edited the set for shops to use $mergeObjects instead. So it only specifies the brand fields when setting brands.


db.products.update({},
[
  {
    $set: {
      // create new brandIDs based on index
      "brands": {
        $map: {
          input: "$brands",
          as: "brand",
          in: {
            "name": "$$brand.name",
            "id": {
              $add: [
                { $indexOfArray: ["$brands", "$$brand"] },
                1
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      },
      // also create shop-brandIDs based on their index
      "shops": {
        $map: {
          input: "$shops",
          as: "shop",
          in: {
            $mergeObjects: [
              "$$shop",
              {
                "brands": {
                  $map: {
                    input: "$$shop.brands",
                    as: "shop_brand",
                    in: {
                      $add: [
                        { $indexOfArray: ["$brands", { "name": "$$shop_brand" }] },
                        1
                      ]
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
],
{ multi: true }
)

Mongo Playground
(Previous Mongo Playground)
Note:

Use updateMany with this; I'm using update with {multi: true} only for Mongo playground. Also, you may not need the pipeline array syntax [] since it's only one $set step. But it doesn't work on playground without it.
In the example data used, I've added more brands in different orders & having multiple brands per shop.


Thanks it worked like a charm. Is there a way to not have to mention on the map all the other fields that remain unchanged?

Yes, you can use the pattern $mergeObjects: ["$$original", { new_field: new_value } ] for the in param in $map. I'm assuming you have this only for the shops array; since the brand match has to work with { name: "brand name" } so can't have other fields. If so, I'll update that part of the pipeline.

@fnmps I've edited the query to use $mergeObjects so you don't need to specify the other fields for shops.
